# Like query on drupal 7

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I have a problem with like dynamic query on drupal 7, i write the query like this:

```
if ($query->setOption('author', 'lc.lom_entity')) {
    $auth= search_expression_extract($keys, 'author');
    $query->join('linkableobject_contribute', 'lc', 'lc.node_id = l.node_id');
        $query->condition("lc.lom_entity", '%' . $auth . '%', "LIKE");

    }
```

for example i search "prova" with author "prova", and it works, but if i search author "pro" it doesn't work! But with condition LIKE the result should be equals!
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use db_like().

```
$query->condition('lc.lom_entity', db_like($auth) . '%', 'LIKE')
```